# Typescript how to include types conditionally?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a case where I need to include types conditionally in Typescript. I'm not 100% sure even its possible using Typescript.

I have simplified code in the example below.

```
type FlexBoxType = {
  inline?: boolean;
  justifyContent?: string;
  alignItems?: string;
    
  /* and so on */
}

type FlexItemType = {
  box?: boolean;
  flex?: string|number;
  shrink?: string | number;

  /* and so on */
}

type FlexItemProps = 
  | FlexItemType & { box: true } & FlexBoxType
  | FlexItemType;

const flexItemStylesGenerator = (args: FlexItemProps) => {
  /* function to generate flex-item styles */

  if(args.box) {
    /* args includes props of FlexBoxType and FlexItemType */
  }
  else {
    /* args includes props of FlexItemType only */
  }

};
```

I have created a function `flexItemStylesGenerator` which generates CSS styles using the passed arguments. If the **box** props is true, then user can specify `FlexItemType` as well `FlexBoxType` props otherwise `FlexItemType` props only.

But then, above types are not working as expected

```
flexItemStylesGenerator({ flex: 1 }); // works properly, as expected
flexItemStylesGenerator({ jusifyContent: 'space-between' }); // gives warning, as expected cannot use FlexBoxType prop without passing box: true.
flexItemStylesGenerator({ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'space-between' }); // no warning, unexpected
```

So how to declare `FlexItemProps` types so user can only pass `FlexBoxType` props when **box** prop is set to true ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `never` type to exclusive type.

```
type Never<T> = {[P in keyof T]?: never}

type FlexItemProps = 
  | FlexItemType & { box: true } & FlexBoxType
  | FlexItemType & Never<FlexBoxType>
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAchBuEBOAeAKgPigXigbwG0AFKASwDsoBrCEAewDMo0BdAfgC4pyFkBfAFADQkKADEANhAAeAITrS04aLjwCoZchIoROUAEZ06UgIbkA3OqgArAK4BnYKQYgAwnXLAInvY6QUAc0sNE20A8gBJLwBbe19gf3Igqw0rAHoAKigzABMoezooDygMtIFBYWVxKWkoiGilUVUrQ2k9Q2MIM2CoBhr4xICAH3JbaP1kHvsAC0SqAcCoIe4xiaRLdKzc-MLi0vKhEWhJGTrooiQ6MHscKCtlk9qYxugAMnwDBS4E22g%20KHej3kimU92qp2eVXecEQqCBCheGCEAGMPI5ejUzgBlUBSewAcW8yBMwDoSFuAAoTEgAvYuI8zhcrvYAJQ4LBqDSZXq2cjIpzFUlQAJEpAk6B9GQAWlIMXyuIgN32VmcVJp9gAdK02ZyNFBudTaZpkRJbDlFVAwJdrkUmPCQaJtgzIaJ9hpBBoIBJ7NBdVyturjabzTcrczbeCnvUXkUtCASmV3UI%20BsBJKo9EcSA8YSeGLSUgKXgMTIuABGKB8FnmfVpKAAdzJVFD1uQEhAABpsjcZJB%20RAcmnMTEsznRSSyUWbA5nG4PF5PFwAOT2MAmZEQKUTYD1iDeJeV6u14WkRA3evU8iBLsmHvSPtePLIszkOjAKAOY41YExsNgBuytMdC2O%20a72PYiytN8SC-BqQ4QvUo6KrmxIFlO6bll2diOLO7ieN4wDLqu66btuu77oeNZpHWr4Npe14fjw94QP2ORAA)

The `never` type will opt-out type guard.

Comment: Thank you @ngiepit, this solved my issues. Wanted to understand why adding `Never<FlexBoxType>` is required ? If you point to article link or documentation, will be very grateful.

Comment: `Never` in this case makes sure that `FlexItemType & Never<FlexBoxType>` does not have any props from `FlexBoxType`. Check next example: `type A = {age:never, name:string}`. Here you are able to use only `A.name`